# Spring JDBC template connection management

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, connection

I am using Spring Framework to manage the transaction and connection, but my question is that whether there is a way to verify the DB connection is closed successfully or not after every DB communication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to enable jdbc driver logs. Normally connection pools also do provide ways to detect connection leaks. For tomcat jdbc connection pool does it by providing few properties.

[Connection Leaks](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/#Connection_leaks)

> **removeAbandoned** = true – Flag to remove abandoned connections if they
> exceed the removeAbandonedTimeout. A connection is considered
> abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been in use longer than
> the removeAbandonedTimeout. This way db connections can be recovered
> from applications that fail to close a connection.
>
> **removeAbandonedTimeout** = 54 – timeout in seconds before an
> abandoned(in use) connection can be removed. The value should be set
> to the longest running query your applications might have.
>
> **validationQuery**= "SELECT 1" – MySql SQL query used to validate
> connections from the pool before returning them to the caller

Apart from this you could rely on spring doing its job :)